# Protect text in symbols from overriding by graphic styles in illustrator cs5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

Setting graphic styles for symbols affect all elements in that symbol, including text. I need it to stay as it is. Is there a way to protect some elements (text, in my case) from being altered by graphic styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by applying styles to the symbols themselves. THe entire purpose of symbols is that they are identical elements.

You can duplicate a symbol, edit the specific internal elements and apply styles to those. Then use that new symbol.

You would need a separate symbol for each different internal appearance.